# simr Power analysis consistently yields low power

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, simulation, statistical-power

I've been running the following code:

```r
# Load the required library
library(simr)

# Set parameters for the simulation
n_clusters    <- 24  # Number of clusters
n_per_cluster <- 10  # Number of observations per cluster
rho           <- 0.8  
              # Intraclass correlation coefficient (moderate clustering)
sigma         <- 0.5  # Residual standard deviation (moderate variability)
effect_size   <- 0.5  # Desired effect size (Cohen's d)
alpha         <- 0.01  # Significance level

# Create a cluster object
clusters <- factor(rep(1:n_clusters, each = n_per_cluster))

# Simulate data with specified parameters
set.seed(42)  # Set seed for reproducibility
sim_data <- data.frame(cluster = clusters,
                       x = rnorm(n_clusters * n_per_cluster),
                       y = rnorm(n_clusters * n_per_cluster, 
                       mean = effect_size * x, sd = sigma))

# Create a mixed-effects model with the simr package
model <- lmer(y ~ x + (1 | cluster), data = sim_data)

# Perform power analysis using the simr package
power_analysis <- powerSim(model, nsim = 5000, alpha = alpha)

# Print the power analysis results
print(power_analysis)
```

This is to simulate a target sample size for a study. I have three experimental conditions, each with two levels, and I am collecting data four times.

However, no matter how I change the parameters, I haven't managed to get power higher than 7%, even when I try parameters which logically should give a very high power (e.g. giant sample size). What am I doing wrong? Or is something wrong with the code?

Comment: Which sample size are you making giant?

Comment: What do you think the parameters *do*? There is no 'effect', you only have a single predictor that is equally correlated to the outcome in all of your observations. You are effectively simulating a null distribution.

Comment: Hi Elena. Besides the comment by Pbulls, there's a problem with your code: you call the variable "x" in the line where `effect_size * x` appears, but `x` is defined nowhere before in the code you shared, which makes it not reproductible.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your simulation is that there is no meaningful 'effect'. You are simulating a standard normal distribution for your predictor and then a second normal distribution, centered on the predictor scaled by `effect_size` and with a residual of `sigma`, for the outcome. This is all well and good but it applies to *all observations* in your simulation. For there to be an effect you need to introduce a systematic difference somewhere, all you are testing at this moment is whether your type I error rate holds under the null.

I would propose you add an additional predictor, let's call it `treatment`, and allocate each observation randomly as either having it or not with 50/50 chance. You mention that you have multiple levels but I leave it up to you to extend this allocation scheme. If you make it so that `effect` only applies to those observations that have specific `treatment`, you have introduced a difference that you can model. Make sure to include `treatment` as a predictor as well!

Another smaller issue is that you are fitting a random effect that does nothing either, all clusters are the same. This will make computations of the random effect parameter problematic as it is entirely competing against the residual variance. For that reason I'd also suggest that you throw in an actual random intercept per cluster. Updated code could look like so:

```
# Set parameters for the simulation
n_clusters    <- 24  # Number of clusters
n_per_cluster <- 10  # Number of observations per cluster
sigma         <- 0.5  # Residual standard deviation (moderate variability)
effect        <- 0.5
alpha         <- 0.01  # Significance level

# Create a cluster object
clusters <- rep(1:n_clusters, each = n_per_cluster)
N <- n_clusters * n_per_cluster

# Simulate data with specified parameters
set.seed(42)  # Set seed for reproducibility

cluster_intercept <- rnorm(n_clusters, mean = 0, sd = 5)
x <- rnorm(N, mean = cluster_intercept[clusters])
treatment <- sample(0:1, N, replace = TRUE)
y <- rnorm(N, mean = x + treatment*effect, sd = sigma)

model <- lme4::lmer(y ~ treatment + x + (1 | clusters))
```

This runs fine and you will actually be able to test the power of `treatment` by varying `effect` and/or sample size. When I run the next step on my machine (`R 4.3.1 + simr 1.0.7 + lme4 1.1.34`) the simulations seem to complete but then crash with `Error in getData(fit) : Couldn't find object's data.`, so I cannot  take you any further than this.

I've removed a few superfluous parameters and there seems to be some confusion in the naming: you are defining correlation but not simulating any, and "Cohen's d" is a standardized effect (mean / standard deviation) whereas in both your code and mine it is expressed in absolute magnitude. Either way the above can be a building block towards a more complex - and realistic - simulation.

Comment: Almost entirely unrelated, I use `sample` because it feels dirty to do `rbinom(size=1)` instead of the non-existing `rbern`, but after benchmarking the latter seems to be faster. This prompts reflection on `fortunes::fortune(98)` ("what are you going to do in the 7ms you saved?") - answer: it's no longer 7ms if you're doing it a million times.